# Helper method for url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have multiple fields for social networking websites where users can enter their username and it would link to their twitter, facebook, myspace account etc. My problem is how can I have it so when a user enters their username I can link to their account.

Here's what I have and I know this is probably not correct. In my profile index.html

```
<%= link_to twitter_url %>
```

profile helper method

```
def twitter_url
  return(self.url= "http://twitter.com/#{profile.twitter}/account")
end
```

In my profile controller

```
include ProfilesHelper
```

The actual field in database is called

```
twitter_link
```

How can I get the just the user username then on my part which will do the rest link to their twitter, facebook etc account page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is that method supposed to know what the `profile` object is without you passing it in?

I'm imagining there being a `@profile` variable defined in your controller. In the view, you would have this:

```
<%= link_to twitter_url %>
```

And in the helper, this:

```
def twitter_url
  "http://twitter.com/#{@profile.twitter_link}/account"
end
```

Note here that you don't need to set `self.url` or have an explicit return. This is because the method will automatically return a `String` which is what `link_to` takes.

If you want this method to be in a helper that's available in *just* your `ProfileController`, then why not put it inside `ProfileHelper` so that it's automatically included just by being related by name?

Comment: I get the `undefined method twitter for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @coletrain, Above solution should be working, could u post the full stack trace to locate the error

Comment: very weird but it worked after I deleted code and retyped it. Thanks Ryan the above code was correct.